# How to spawn multiple "monsters" from a single class

Tags: java

How to spawn multiple "monsters" from a single class? Can store it in an array, ok, but later on, how can I paint it? Because if I do:

```
enemy = new Enemy();
enemy2 = new Enemy();
```

I create two instances of the object, but after how can I paint it?

I use:

```
g2d.drawImage(Enemy.getImage(), Enemy.getX(), Enemy.getY(), this);
```

But obviously it uses the class, not the variable.
Images will not be overlaid because coordinates are random.

Enemy's structured like:

```
public class Enemy {
static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
private int x;
private int y;
private Image image;
private int dx;
private int dy;
private int i;
private int strength=10;
private static int hp=100;
public String EnemyP = "/image/cazzillo_base_definitivo_000.png";

public Enemy() {    //Set skin and enemy position

    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(EnemyP));
    image = ii.getImage();
    x = randomGenerator.nextInt(1024);
    y = randomGenerator.nextInt(700);
}

public int getX() { //Get function
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void move() {    //Movement with delay
    if(i==6){
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    }
}
public void follow () { //Function that follow the main character
    if (Cazzillo.getX()>x)  //Cazzillo it's the character class
        dx=1;
    else if (Cazzillo.getX()<x)
        dx=-1;
    else
        dx=0;
    if (Cazzillo.getY()>y)
        dy=1;
    else if (Cazzillo.getY()<y)
        dy=-1;
    else
        dy=0;
    if(i<6)
        i++;
    else
        i=0;
}

public void attack () { //Attack function not implemented yet
}
public void attacked (){    //Function that is activated when enemy's attacked
    hp -=Cazzillo.getS();
    if (hp<=0)  
        death();
}
public void death (){
        x=randomGenerator.nextInt(1024);
        y=randomGenerator.nextInt(700);
        hp=100;
}
}
```

Comment: code snippet is insufficient to answer, consider [edit]ing to at least explain how `Enemy` methods are defined

Comment: Added how it's structured Enemy class. Excuse me if it's not optimized, i'm here to learn.

Comment: interesting. Did you try the code in the snippet? `Enemy.getImage(), Enemy.getX(), Enemy.getY()` won't compile because `getImage` etc are instance methods

Comment: please avoid doing [edits to the question that invalidate existing answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254524/839601)

Comment: So how can I update the code? Should I open a new question?

Comment: askers are expected to open new question in cases like this. By the way, by looking at [your attempt here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/260813/6), it appears 1) off-topic for Programmers (implementation issue) and 2) insufficient quality for Stack Overflow - incomplete stack trace, [vague debugging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601)

Answer (score 5):

> But obviously it use the class, not the variable.

Well, that is obviously wrong. You do have to use the instance:

```
g2d.drawImage(enemy.getImage(), enemy.getX(), enemy.getY(), this);
g2d.drawImage(enemy2.getImage(), enemy2.getX(), enemy2.getY(), this);
```

Of course that means that those methods need to be instance methods and their data stored in non-static fields. That's what OOP is all about: having separate objects which hold their own data and have methods that operate on the object's data. Classes are just templates for multiple object instances. Class/static methods (and especially fields) are an aberration that should be avoided.

Comment: How can i avoid it?

Comment: @Giampli: use instance methods and fields instead.

Comment: Saying that static methods are an aberration that should be avoided is misleading. Global state is what should be avoided. Sometimes a static method is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Doval: with regard to the scope of the question the advice seems correct to me. Discussing theoretical subtleties and nuances of when to use a static method/class and when not will not help much here, IMHO. Except that, you are right (and the "abberation" point is surely debatable).